# how to get all friends list including the deactivated ones using fql or graph api?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

now I have 455 friends in the list as its on the facebook wall of mine

but when I try to get it, the result is 432 friends

I tried to use both FQL query and Graph api ..

I also tested it with and without LIMIT 0 and LIMIT 5000

nothing was able to get the entire list !!!

I googled it and found out in the link below that I should modify the query to get the friends list including the deactivated ones !!!
[link to the page](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/372544796150963)

> I also searched for it on facebook developers site with no result

**the Querstion is:** how can I get the user full friends list same as it is on his wall?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The API does not return deactivated users in the friends list, this is only visible on facebook.com

Comment: there is too many applications can get it. you may see "Friend Check" for iphone :)

Comment: That app doesn't use the API, it scrapes facebook.com